# Connect to remote MySQL via Python

Tags: python, mysql, database, server

I have installed MySQL on a remote server. I also created some databases with some tables in them, all via SSH.

I have created the following users:

```
CREATE USER 'myname'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
CREATE USER 'remotMe'@'myIP' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';

GRANT PRIVILEGES * . * TO 'myname'@'localhost';
GRANT PRIVILEGES * . * TO 'remoteMe'@'myIP';
```

Now, I would like to connect to this MySQL server via Python. I have installed [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL). I am trying out the following code:

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='ServerIP', port=3306, user='remoteMe', passwd='mypassword', db='myDB')
```

But this gives me a `connection refused` error. Do I need to configure something else to make this work?

Comment: Check if you have successfully connect to the MySQL server using a MySQL client first. If not, it's likely that your remote access for MySQL serer has not worked yet

Comment: Check remote server open port on which MySQL server has to listen.

Comment: @btquanto I tried using Navicat, but it gives me the following error: `Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0`
@Lafada How do I check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely MySQL is bound to localhost. Assuming you're using a Linux machine:

On your remote machine, edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Find `bind-address=127.0.0.1`, edit it to `bind-address=0.0.0.0`, or just remove the line.

Restart MySQL

Read more: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address

Comment: When I do this, will I be able to connect to MySQL via both localhost and remote?

Comment: You should be. Changing it would allow you to bind to any network interfaces

Comment: From MySQL documentation:
If the address is 0.0.0.0, the server accepts TCP/IP connections on all server host IPv4 interfaces. If the address is a “regular” IPv4 address (such as 127.0.0.1), the server accepts TCP/IP connections only for that particular IPv4 address.

Comment: I have changed the `my.cnf` file and restarted MySQL, but I still get the connection refused error when I run the Python code on my local machine.

Comment: What about connecting from Navicat?

Comment: Now I get `No connection initailized yet (Resource pointer still NULL)` or still the same error as before.

Answer (score 1):

The `connection refused` error message actual means that it was not possible to open a TCP socket. The server refused the connection. This is not related to the authentication or user permissions since the refusal happens on the OS level before the MySQL server is involved. Possible causes are:

- the MySQL server is bound to localhost only → set the listening address to the servers real IP address or 0.0.0.0 in mysql.conf
- there is a firewall in between → reconfigure/deactivate the firewall
- your connection details (server/port) are wrong → check them again